# number of characters left in a bash variable?

Tags: bash

How can I, in a bash script, have a variable of 300 characters that can be input into it, and it displays the number of characters left please? In this case the characters will be numbers corresponding to a feed from get-iplayer, with a maximum of 4 characters in a block separated from the next by a space. The relevant script follows -

```
!#/bin/bash
{
    read -n1 -p "Do you want to download some tv programmes? [y/n/q] " ynq ;
case "$ynq" in 
    [Yy]) echo
  read -n300 -p "Please input the tv programme numbers to download [max 300 characters]  " 'tvbox'
          echo
          cd /media/$USER/back2/proggies/
          /usr/bin/get-iplayer --get $tvbox
          ;;
    [Nn]) echo;;     # moves on to next question in the script
    [Qq]) echo; exit;;            # quits
    * ) echo "Thank you ";;
 esac
```

};

What I'm looking for is a countdown of characters left in 'tvbox', which starts at 300. The inputted numbers will range from 15 to 2000, and will be separated by spaces, but these spaces will also count towards the final total. Can it be done please?

Comment: Note to readers: same question on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21338070/7552

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was [cross posted to Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338070/an-input-prompt-that-dynamically-reflects-the-number-of-characters-as-you-type).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This reads one program number at a time and provides a countdown of the number of characters available:

```
while true
do
    ((chars_left = 300 -${#tvbox}))
    read -p "Input a program number of up to $chars_left characters or type 'quit' when done: " new_pgm
    [ "$new_pgm" = quit ] && break
    if [ $chars_left -gt ${#new_pgm} ]
    then
        tvbox="$tvbox $new_pgm"
    else
        echo "Sorry.  You are over your character limit."
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much, this works extremely well.